# unity ошибка CS0117 помогите решить

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

[image]
error CS0117: 'Time' does not contain a definition for 'deltatime'

Показываю скриншот ошибки и текст ошибки и скриншот кода который писал. немогу исправить эту ошибку ,как я понял она возникает из-за того что "delta.time" устарела и нужно использовать другой текст для этой функции.Кто может помочь ? я могу ошибаться.Если знаете как решить опишите пожалуйста.

[image: unity]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка говорит что у класса `Time` отсутствует свойство `deltatime`.
Попробуйте так: `Time.deltaTime`.

Comment: непомогло попробовал

Comment: Показываете ошибку после изменения на `Time.deltaTime`

Comment: Спасибо ошибся все заработало .Поможете еще с одним вопросом?

Comment: @FrendGameCompany Создавайте новый вопрос, не тут. Я всегда смотрю вопросы связанные с Unity, если знаю ответ - помогу.

Comment: @FrendGameCompany и отметьте ответ галочкой, если помогло.